# Does there exist a group with only one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My only thoughts would be something like the set Z and using the number 1 but even then would that be able to satisfy the invertible condition?

Comment: It's perhaps a good to ask about other sizes as well such as $2$ or $3$. It's also good to ask weather the group of these sizes is unique.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_group).  It arises naturally in certain scenarios e.g. as the kernel of an injective homomorphism.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: You can call the single element anything you want. Call it $w$.  But think about it.  Can you make a table of $a*b=c$ with only one element.  Well... $a, b,c $ all have to be $w $ and you have $w*w=w $.  That's it.  You need an identity element.  That's $w $. Each element needs an inverse.  So that's $w'=w $.  That's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, if you let $1+1=1$.  (I know this is not what you wanted:  I had to "disturb" the operation to make this work out.  This is not natural.)

With only one element $x$ there is only one operation:  $x*x=x$.  This is called the trivial group $(\{x\}, *)$.

In $\mathbb{Z}$ under $+$, the only 1-element subgroup is $\{0\}$.  In general, the only one-element subgroup inside of any group $G$ is $\{e\}$, where $e \in G$ is the identity.